# IndexError: index X is out of bounds for axis 0 with size Y

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, indexing

help me with error please? and how to save the output from print function to dataframe?

```
from haversine import haversine
import pandas as pd

dataframe = pd.read_csv("gpsdataedit.csv", delimiter = None)
dataset = dataframe.values
n = 0
c = 0
b = 1
a = dataset

for value in  enumerate(dataset) :
    c = c + 1
    b = b +1
    n = n + 1
    distance = haversine(a[c], a[b]).km
    print(distance)
```

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>       File "/home/rr/PycharmProjects/GPS/trydistance.py", line 32, in <module>
>       distance = haversine(a[c], a[b]).km
>       IndexError: index 151 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 151

Comment: Please indent your code appropriately, It is not clear which statements are in the loop.

Comment: sorry...update already

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, ditch all the extraneous indexers.

```
for x, y in enumerate(zip(dataset, dataset[1:])):
    distance = haversine(x, y).km
    print(distance)
```